# How to delete nested new in C++

Tags: c++, raii

In [ref](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/2), they have this line of code

```
Widget *aWidget = new BorderDecorator(new BorderDecorator(new ScrollDecorator
(new TextField(80, 24))));
```

Two questions:

> Say, I want to explicitly delete the objects created with new.  How do
>   you do that?
>
> BTW, If I just add
>
> ```
> delete aWidget;
> ```
>
> I get warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'Widget'
>   which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour
>   [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]

Second related question:

> How do you write this nested news with unique_ptr

Thanks

Comment: @tadman: You mean `Widget` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: Since you tagged this [tag:raii], it seems that you know that the solution is RAII and have at least heard of it . . . ?

Comment: Time to learn about `std::shared_ptr` etc...

Comment: Do you have control over the implementations of `Widget`, `BorderDecorator`, `ScrollDecorator`, and `TextField`?

Comment: Why do all these constructors take pointers?!

Comment: @David: The decorator pattern is built that way.  See the reference: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/2

Comment: This seems like a truly awful pattern to me because it's not clear who owns what.

Comment: It probably got borged from Java and hasn't found a good implementation yet. And this is a mistake I would not want to see in a textbook: `class Widget
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};` Compiler is 100% on the nose to complain.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, the implementation that was linked is awful. The general idea of the pattern is probably sane.

Comment: My advice then would simply be to ignore that page. It definitely looks like it was not actually designed to be C++ code but was Java code that was minimally changed with the intent of illustrating the pattern, not showing how to actually implement the pattern in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you're following glosses over all the memory management. It's likely to lead to bad habits.

To properly manage memory, you could simply avoid dynamic allocations:

```
TextField textField(80, 24);
ScrollDecorator scrollDecorator(&textField);
BorderDecorator bd1(&scrollDecorator);
BorderDecorator bd2(&bd1);
Widget *aWidget = &bd2;
```

No `new`s is good news!

And `Widget` really, really should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: "No `new`s is good news!". Amen. Here is a few slides that also explains this: http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp.pdf

Comment: @gurka: As far as I'm aware, I just coined that phrase myself (in this context, meaning C++ `new`). I think it's going to be my new motto.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't that you're deleting the object, your problem is that you're deleting a potentially polymorphic object which doesn't have a `virtual` destructor, which leaves the possibility that the most derived class won't be properly cleaned up.

[See here for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461224/1007504)